# Is there a CacheService equivalent in Craft 3?

Tags: cache

[CacheService](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-cacheservice.html) is exactly what I need to cache a custom API endpoint in PHP, but I don't see it in Craft 3. What would be the correct way to do this in Craft 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still there, but you're working at the Yii2 layer: [The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0: Data Caching](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data)